# Setting Include Path in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have looked at [this page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html) to set up an include path for my header files.

But when I try to set it up like this:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/breakpad/src
```

I get this error:

```
export $C_INCLUDE_PATH
-bash: export: `/home/ubuntu/breakpad/src/': not a valid identifier
```

Why is that?

Comment: You should learn about [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and write your own `Makefile`-s, then build your complex (multi-file) project with simply `make`

Answer (score 1):

Export the variable:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Note that there is no `$`

FYI: this expansion lets you do clever things like:

```
$ export FOO=BAR
$ export $FOO=baz
$ echo $BAR
baz
```